# How do I access the calendars under my "Shared Calendars"?

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I am currently trying to write an Outlook macro that receives information about an appointment that needs to be set, and then automatically adds it to the correct folders.

One of the folders doesn't seem to have a location. I have it saved under my **"Shared Calendars"**, and can be found on the **"Public Folders"** part of the folders section. I can't figure out a way to access it via VBA.

I have not found anything that has helped me. Ideally I would be able to list all of the available calendars in one of these locations and then have some way to select them.

Note - It is not a person's shared folder so can't be accessed by doing

```
.GetSharedDefaultFolder
```

I looked at [Working with VBA and non-default Outlook Folders](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/) but couldn't make any of them work how I wanted.

I am using Outlook 2013

Just to clarify. Ideally, I want to show all the folders in the **"Shared Calendars"**, so that I can then select one of the folders and add to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself!!

So using the Locals window I was able to find path to the folder I wanted to access. Then was able to use:

```
NameSpace.Folders.item("NAME")
```

Note for anyone trying - The path can't have the original "\\" on the beginning of the path.